# Clickable row in Table

Tags: django, reactjs, api, row

I have a backend written in Django and I'm using REST API for connecting it with React frontend. I have a table that is fulfilled with data that I'm getting from my API.

The question is how to make those rows clickable so when I click on table row I get more info about what that row represents. I would need to open a new page which will display more information about that specific row.

Answer (score 1):

to make a row clickable , just add a onClick property to the  tag which points to the method/function in your element.
something like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class App extends Component {
              constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={rowDetails:''};
    this.doSomething=this.doSomething.bind(this);

    }
    doSomething=()=>{
    this.setState({rowDetails:"the details about the clicked row"})
    }

    render(){
      return(
    <table>
    <tr onClick={this.doSomething} >
            <td>cell data</td>
            <td>cell data</td>
    </tr>
    <p> {this.state.rowDetails} </p>
    </table>
      )
    }
    }
```

Comment: if any clarifications required I will be happy to assist

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you. Try to add `onClick` event into your **tr**, something like this

```
const Table = (props) => (
    <tr onClick={e => this.doSomething(e)}>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
);

doSomething(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

In the doSomething() function, you can write your function to fetch data redirect using `props.history.push("route-name");`.